# MacOs cannot download Tomcat server from STS

Tags: spring, macos, tomcat, spring-tool-suite

I am trying to run newly downloaded STS tool on MacOs. When i try to add new Tomcat 7 server the button "Download and Install" remains inactive, I cannot understand why?

If I choose workspace directory as installation directory in gives me an error message "Unknown version of Tomcat was specified"

Comment: I think this button is provided by the wizard, but individual server adapters need to provide the functionality behind it in order to download and install server runtimes. And this doesn't seem to be the case for the tomcat servers, so you need to download them from the Apache website and configure them in the wizard instead of downloading them.

Comment: in case you are working on Spring Boot apps, they usually come with an embedded Tomcat, so you won't need to download and install a separate Tomcat server on your machine - just in case you think about working with Spring Boot in STS.